# How to sort a category by its subcategories

Tags: category, sort

i need to sort my products on the category page by thier subcategories can someone tell me what i am doing wrong with this?

```
   $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->clear()->setOrder('category_ids first_item', 'asc');
```